# Repetitive Error: shapes (1,3) and (100,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 100 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am getting this error after every code section that I'm executing and I'm unable to resolve this issue. Following is the code:
**Please need to resolve this issue**

**Cost Function**

```
def compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y):    
    m=len(y)
    J = (1/m) * np.sum((-y * np.log(h(theta,X))) - ((1-y)*np.log(1-h(theta,X))))
    eps = 1e-12
    h[h < eps] = eps
    eps = 1.0 - 1e-12
    h[h > eps] = eps

    return J


# Recall that for a model with inputs, we actually use 3 parameters, theta_0, theta_1 
# and theta_2.  The inputs X need to have an initial column of all 1's for the theta_0
# parameter.  So for our current data, X needs to be a 3xm shaped set of data, where 
# the first value in each column is 1.0, and the next value in each column is our raw inputs
X = np.ones( (3, m) )
X[1:,:] = X.T # the second column contains the raw inputs
```

*An Error:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-596c409301b0> in <module>
4 # the first value in each column is 1.0, and the next value in each column is our raw 
inputs
5 X = np.ones( (3, m) )
----> 6 X[1:,:] = X.T # the second column contains the raw inputs

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (2,3)
```

**The calculating threshold value for a given hypothesis**

```
theta = np.zeros( (3, 1) )
print(theta)
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))


theta = np.array([[1.0],
              [1.0],
              [1.0]])

print(theta)

print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))

theta = np.array([[0.1],
              [0.1],
              [0.1]])
print(theta)
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))
```

*An error again:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-d07eafdd63a5> in <module>
  2 print(theta)
  3 print("Hello")
  ----> 4 print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))
  5 
  6 

 <ipython-input-90-88cf8ecf55dc> in compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y)
 24     h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
 25 
 ---> 26     J = -1*(1/m)*(np.log(h).T.dot(y)+np.log(1-h).T.dot(1-y))
 27 
 28     if np.isnan(J[0]):

 ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (100,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 100 (dim 0)
```

**Computing Gradient function:**

```
def compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y):
    m = y.size
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta.reshape(-1,1)))

    grad =(1/m)*X.T.dot(h-y)

    return(grad)


theta = np.zeros( (3, 1) )
print(compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y))
# Expected Result >>> [ -0.1        -12.00921659 -11.26284221]
theta = np.array([[1.0],
              [1.0],
              [1.0]])
print(compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y))
# Expected Result >>> [  0.4         20.81292044  21.84815684]
theta = np.array([[0.1],
              [0.1],
              [0.1]])
print(compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y))
# Expected Result >>> [  0.39997223  20.81184964  21.84684953]
```

*An Error again*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-f8672fbf30fe> in <module>
  1 theta = np.zeros( (3, 1) )
----> 2 print(compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y))
  3 
  4 theta = np.array([[1.0],
  5                   [1.0],

<ipython-input-107-0af7d4f48cd7> in compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y)
  1 def compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y):
  2     m = y.size
----> 3     h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta.reshape(-1,1)))
  4 
  5     grad =(1/m)*X.T.dot(h-y)

ValueError: shapes (100,2) and (3,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

**Parameters using SciPy Optimize**

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
theta = np.zeros( 2 ) # initial theta parameters to start gradient descent from
res = minimize(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y), theta, method='CG', 
           jac=compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y), 
           options={'disp': True})
print(res.x)
```

*An Error*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-bc65484d35ef> in <module>
  1 from scipy.optimize import minimize
  2 theta = np.zeros( 2 ) # initial theta parameters to start gradient descent from
 ----> 3 res = minimize(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y), theta, method='CG', 
  4                jac=compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y),
  5                options={'disp': True})

 <ipython-input-90-88cf8ecf55dc> in compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y)
 22     """
 23     m = y.size
 ---> 24     h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
 25 
 26     J = -1*(1/m)*(np.log(h).T.dot(y)+np.log(1-h).T.dot(1-y))

 ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (2,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

**Trying to plot the scatter plot:**

```
res = minimize(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y), theta, method='CG', 
           jac=compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y), 
           options={'disp': True})

plt.plot(x[val1, 0], X[val1, 1], linestyle='', marker='^', color='r')
plt.plot(x[val2, 0], X[val2, 1], linestyle='', marker='o', color='y')
# Assigning the calculated θ to a variable
gradBFGS = res['x']

# Calculating x and y for the decision boundary
plot_x = np.array([np.min(X[:, 2])-1, np.max(X[:, 2])+1])

# From the decision boundary calculations x2 = (-1 / θ2) * (θ0 * x1 + θ0)
plot_y = (-1 / gradBFGS[2]) * (gradBFGS[1] * plot_x + gradBFGS[0])
plt.scatter(45, 85, s=30, c='r', marker='x')

# Plotting the data
plotData(X[:,1:], y, 'Exam 1 score', 'Exam 2 score', 'Admitted', 'Not Admitted')
plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, c='b');
```

*An Error*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-a46335302bf6> in <module>
----> 1 res = minimize(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y), theta, method='CG', 
  2                jac=compute_logistic_cost_gradients(theta, X, y),
  3                options={'disp': True})
  4 
  5 # Assigning the calculated θ to a variable

<ipython-input-90-88cf8ecf55dc> in compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y)
 22     """
 23     m = y.size
---> 24     h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
 25 
 26     J = -1*(1/m)*(np.log(h).T.dot(y)+np.log(1-h).T.dot(1-y))

ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (2,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these errors are due to the dimensions of your numpy arrays not being compatible for the operations you're attempting. For example, in the first section you're trying to assign an array with shape (3, 3) into an array of shape (2, 3).

```
 ----> 6 X[1:,:] = X.T # the second column contains the raw inputs

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (2,3)
```

Note that these arrays are 0 indexed so `X[1:,:]` is grabbing only the 2nd and 3rd rows of that matrix. All the errors are because of these shape mismatches, in other cases because of incompatible shapes in the dot products.

If you're trying to add an intercept to raw data maybe this is what you're looking for

```
intercept = np.ones((3, 1))

raw_data = np.zeros((3, 3))

X = np.hstack([intercept, raw_data])
```

Comment: I have tried to reshape it and tried some other variations to get the value but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: to start, what is the intent of these two lines?  
X = np.ones( (3, m) ) . 
X[1:,:] = X.T # the second column contains the raw inputs .

Comment: Yes, It consists raw input from .csv flie

Comment: X wont contain any raw inputs here. It's just a 3x3 array full of 1s as you define it in the first of those two lines

Comment: Yeah, you are right but what is the possible way that I can get the proper flow in code?

Comment: I added code to my answer above that might be doing what you want. Assuming you want a column of 1s in front of your data for an intercept?

Comment: Well, It didn't help, and I'm trying trying to learn logistic regression here and those are the steps code by code given above.